# query that returns all suppliers that provide exactly 2 categories of items

Tags: sql

We have a big table of products with the relevant rows `ProductID, SupplierID, CategoryID`.

I need to write query that returns all suppliers that provide exactly 2 categories of items.

```
select Products.SupplierID, CompanyName, Products.CategoryID, CategoryName
from Products 
join Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
join SUPPLIERS ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
where Products.SupplierID = ANY (
    select top 3 with ties Products.SupplierID
    from Products
    group by Products.SupplierID
    order by count(*) desc);
```

Comment: Please specify the example with examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you would just need to change your WHERE Statement to look for the Supplier ID's that have 2 distinct CategoryID's. You are really close, it would just be removing the Top 3 and Order by, then adding a HAVING statement at the end showing `COUNT(DISTINCT(Products.CatigoryID)) = 2`.

I hope that helps get you where you need to go.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: That is great to hear!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    SupplierId
FROM
    Products
GROUP BY
    SupplierId
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) = 2
```

If you don't need the actual categories you can use simple aggregation with a group by and `HAVING` clause.  the `HAVING` is like a `WHERE` after the fact.  So you can also add `WHERE` statements and things too.

Note you don't actual need the `categories` table because product id already has the id on the table.  However it is likely that you have your relationship slightly off and that the `products` table doesn't carry the `categoryids` but your `categories` table carries the `productids` in which case you would need something like this:

```
SELECT
    Products.SupplierId
FROM
    Products
    INNER JOIN Categories
    ON Products.ProductId = Categories.ProductId
GROUP BY
    Products.SupplierId
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT Categories.CategoryID) = 2
```

If you want the actual categories it gets a little more complicated but can be done in a not too different way than your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You did mention subquery so here's my take:

```
select * 
from 
    @suppliers s
    inner join(
        select 
            s.supplierid,
            count(distinct categoryid) cats
        from    
            @products p
            inner join @suppliers s on
                p.supplierid = s.supplierid
        group by
            s.supplierid
        having count(distinct categoryid) = 2
        ) supplieroftwocats on 
            s.supplierid = supplieroftwocats.supplierid
```

Comment: alex why the need for a subquery with the code you presented if you use a simple group by on all of the suppliers columns it would yield you the same result without the subquery.

Comment: Matt the assignment actually specifies that we need to use a subquery

Comment: Weston, would adding a sub query in the Where statement work as well?